# theano running on GPU using terminal not in pycharm

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm, theano, theano-cuda

I have installed Theano + CUDA + CUDNN as per instructions on official webpage.

When I run on terminal:

```
python
import theano
```

I get:

```
Using gpu device 0: GeForce GTX TITAN X (CNMeM is disabled)
```

When I do the same in Pycharm I get:

```
ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): nvcc compiler not found on $PATH. Check your nvcc installation and try again.
```

I have added the CUDA folders to the interpreter path without any success. as you can see in the following pic:

[image]

Any alternative recommendations on how to fix this?

Comment: The interpreter path and `$PATH` are not the same thing. It is a pretty obvious error message.

Comment: So what is the difference and how can I solve this?

Comment: Set `PATH`correctly in your environment, obviously.

Comment: This is how my environment looks like `export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export $PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin:$PATH` I added the last line recently, and the error still appears. Anything else that I have to try?

Comment: Note that you need to set PATH for PyCharm (and the shell which PyCharm runs). This http://stackoverflow.com/q/21581197/681865 is probably the solution.

Comment: I have the same problem. When I type `nvcc` from PyCharm's terminal it finds it, but can't run Theano code.