# How to import own module in PyCharm console

Tags: python, pycharm

I have an own module in my project directory and I import it into my code.

main.py:

```
from my_module import Test

print(Test.test())
```

my_module.py:

```
class Test:
@staticmethod
def test():
    return '123'
```

There is no problem running the code in PyCharm. But when I try to "Execute Selection in Console", I get

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0.4\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named 'my_module'`

How do I import own modules in the PyCharm console?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197970/pycharm-import-external-library) out. Do `import sys` and `print(sys.path)` to see the current paths that will be searched when looking for imports.

Comment: `['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 5.0.4\\helpers\\pydev', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 5.0.4\\helpers\\pydev', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python34.zip', 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\Python34', 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']`

Comment: [A few options](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21488010/6004486)

Comment: You could also do `import sys`, `sys.path.append("/full/path/to/folder/containing/my_module.py")`

Comment: I only tried `import sys`, `sys.path.append("/full/path/to/folder/containing/my_module.py")` and it worked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can also instruct PyCharm to add source roots to `PYTHONPATH` in the Python Console:

- go to File -> Settings (or Default Settings) -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console -> Python Console
- check "*Add source roots to PYTHONPATH*".

For some reason, this option is not activated by default.

Comment: This was active by default for me and didn't solve the problem.

Comment: had a similar problem to you. This didn't solve it for me but the following did. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51916228/12117496

Answer (score 3):

I don't use PyCharm but the problem is caused by environment variables like `PATH` that aren't necessarily available from within a program/IDE.

How to fix it properly/permanently has been discussed numerous times; e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197970/pycharm-import-external-library) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486528/environment-path-different-when-using-venv). Often, running the program from terminal fixes the issue because the program thereby "inherits" the environment variables. Another way is to use this quick fix:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/full/path/to/folder/containing/your_module.py")
# Now, this should work:
import your_module
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was the following:

1. Go to File -> Settings (or Default Settings) -> Build, Execution,
   Deployment -> Console -> Python Console
2. Comment out "sys.path.extend([WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS])"
3. Now I can import modules inside the source roots in the console!

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend(['C:\\Users\\ahmet\\source\\repos\\python-core'])
```

PyCharm adds the root directory for you.

To import a file, you need to prefix the sub-directory name if any as follows

```
from subdirectory.myfile from ClassA
```

Comment: Somehow commenting out the sys.path line as @JohnnyQ suggested, then deleting the subdirectory solved my issue. I am not sure why my experience is opposite of you...