# Different $PATH in Virtual Environments

Tags: python, bash, macos, path

I'm on Mac using only terminal.

Running `echo $PATH` returns

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/username/.cargo/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/Users/username/Venvs/default/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/bin:usr/local/bin:/Users/username/.cargo/bin
```

After activating the venv, `echo $PATH` only returns

```
/Users/username/Venvs/default/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

How do I set i.e. `/Users/username/.cargo/bin` to be loaded by all venvs by default? (now it's set in .zshrc)

I can't find any documentation of how do Virtual environments set the $PATH and why. I can't even figure out where do most of the entries come from.

This is a related question, but does not address why the situation happens when I'm in the terminal the whole time:
[Environment $PATH different when using venv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486528/environment-path-different-when-using-venv)

I have tried to append the `PATH` using all these places with no difference:

```
/etc/bashrc
/etc/profile
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
~/.profile
~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
~/.zshrc
~/.zprofile
```

Comment: Well, you wouldn't expect the two PATHes identical, would you? So the question would rather be: Which PATH component are you missing in which of the two cases?

Comment: I would expect it to be indentical, having an installation of psql or rust is imho independent of Python. Plus I really can't find any info about what the relationship between venvs and $PATH is

Comment: I've added an actual question. How do I get cargo to all venvs by default? (it's not by adding it to .zshrc)

Comment: Are you interested in getting all definitions inside your `.cargo/bin` file, or only the environment variables?

Comment: Everything. I've found the issue already - I've had another venv activation in `.zshenv` that I didn't know about, so all the changes to `$PATH` happened in an activated venv and didn't persist.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a virtual environment is to configure your shell to use a specific Python installation.

While details might vary depending on the tool used to create the virtual environment, typically there is a shell script `activate` that you source which explicitly adds the virtual environment's `bin` directory to your `PATH`. (It also saves the old path, and defines a shell function `deactivate` which restores `PATH` to its previous value.)

Comment: the Python installation is not my point, my issue is the other components of the $PATH missing after I activate.

Comment: I've added an actual question. How do I get cargo to all venvs by default? (it's not by adding it to .zshrc)

Comment: You don't, but you also shouldn't need to. It's not a Python package, and your virtual environment just prepends the venv/bin to your path. Make sure your cargo directory is in `PATH` *before* you start the virtual environment. If you've recently changed your `.zprofile` (use that, not `.zshrc` for environment variables), you'll need to deactivate the venv, update `PATH` (either manually or be starting a new shell session) then reactivating the venv.

Comment: The entry in PATH is there before I activate the venv. After I activate, the entry disappears. Adding to `.zprofile` doesn't help.

Comment: examine the contents of the `activate` script.  It will do only 2 things: prepend some data to your PATH and make you wish to vomit.  A stock activate script does not do very much, and if yours is tweaking your PATH more than simply prepending one directory to it, then something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make `$PATH` different seems to be to activate a virtual environment and *then* append to it.

I use a `default` venv that I'm setting in `.zshrc`, but I have also been setting it in `.zshenv`, which was loaded first. Removing the venv activation from `.zshenv` solved the issue.

So in case there's a difference between your `$PATH` in different venvs, make sure the order of activation and appending is correct.